# Generate pdf using pdfkit in flask - reload page error

Tags: python-3.x, flask, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit, python-pdfkit

I'm trying to convert HTML to pdf using flask.

I can use the following packages.

- pdfkit
- wkhtmltopdf

When I run the server it cant load into the browser even the homepage cant load into the browser. I do not understand what's wrong with it.

HTML markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">

  
    <h1 class="text-center mt-4">Leave Workers Details</h1>
  
    <table class="table mt-4">
        <thead class="table-dark">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Id</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Address</th>
            <th scope="col">Contact</th>
            <th scope="col">LeaveDate</th>
            <th scope="col">Admin</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {% for worker in leave_worker %}
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td> {{ worker.id }}</td>
            <td> {{ worker.leave_worker_name }} </td>
            <td> {{ worker.leave_worker_address }} </td>
            <td> {{ worker.leave_worker_contact }} </td>
            <td> {{ worker.leave_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }} </td>
            <td> {{ worker.admin.username }} </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`route.py` code:

```
config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe')
pdfkit.from_url('http://127.0.0.1:5000/leave_worker_pdf', 'output.pdf', configuration=config)

@app.route('/leave_worker_pdf')
def leave_worker_pdf():
    leave_worker = LeaveWorker.query.all()
    html = render_template(
        "leave_worker_pdf.html",
        leave_worker=leave_worker)
    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False)
    response = make_response(pdf)
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/pdf"
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "inline; filename=output.pdf"
    return response
```

[image: Browser screenshot]

Comment: The browser can not reach your site becuase the server does not know the site, as you have not registered the route with flask.

Comment: My first comment might be wrong. Maybe you just have forgotten to start flask?

Comment: when I remove wkhtmltopdf configuration from my app then my app works fine.when I add wkhtmltopdf configuration to my app then the browser can't load the page.

Comment: Well, if you app works fine without the config then you simply do not need it. Please post the solution as a post an mark it as such.

Comment: @MacOS My app works fine but I can't convert HTML to pdf the app gives this error  `OSError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "b''" If this file exists please check that this process can read it. Otherwise please install wkhtmltopdf - https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit/wiki/Installing-wkhtmltopdf`

Comment: I think you do not have to specify the location of ```wkhtmltopdf```. According to the documentation, it searches for it automatically on linux and windows. On windows, it uses ```where wkhtmltopdf```. Please try it without the explicit config.

Comment: @MacOS can you send me the documentation link?

Comment: @Batcha coder: https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit#configuration

Answer (score 0):

Change

```py
def leave_worker_pdf():
    leave_worker = LeaveWorker.query.all()
    html = render_template(
        "leave_worker_pdf.html",
        leave_worker=leave_worker)
    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False)
    response = make_response(pdf)
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/pdf"
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "inline; filename=output.pdf"
    return response
```

to

```py
@app.route('/leave_worker_pdf')
def leave_worker_pdf():
    leave_worker = LeaveWorker.query.all()
    html = render_template(
        "leave_worker_pdf.html",
        leave_worker=leave_worker)
    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False)
    response = make_response(pdf)
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/pdf"
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "inline; filename=output.pdf"
    return response
```

this assumes that you are working with `app` not not with *blueprints*.

Comment: This answer assumes that you did start flask.

Comment: **I have route**                                                                                    `@app.route('/leave_worker_pdf')